# How to prevent SSIS from writing column names to the flat file output?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

I am getting the output in flat file as shown below.

[image: Flat file output file]

How do I avoid column names from being written to the flat file output?

Comment: In your excel configuration manager, check "First row has column..." option

Comment: Personally I would try to convince whoever wants it this way  to accept the header rows. We do thousands of imports a month and the ones where we have been unable to get header rows from the client take much longer to troubleshoot when there is a problem. HOever @user756519 has the right solution if you are unable to get them to accept a header row.

Answer (score 11):

The best way that I've found to accomplish this is the following:

1. I create a test output flat file.  I populate the .txt file with the result set from the SQL query that will be used in the package.  Make sure that the first row of the .txt file contains the column header names.
2. Create a Flat File Connection.  Point it to the text output flat file.  Check the "Column names in the first data row" box.  This will make sure that the actual column header names will be used/shown, instead of "Column 0", "Column 1", etc.  Click "OK" to close the Flat File Connection Manager.
3. Edit the Flat File Destination item to make sure that the actual column header names are picked up and that the fields are mapped properly between your query and the output columns of your Flat File Connection.  Click "OK".
4. Highlight the Flat File Connection and press "F4" to open the "Properties" window.  There, change the "ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow" to "False".

Now your output flat file will contain data only...no column header row.  Yet you can still go to the Flat File Destination item and see the actual column header names being used there.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd like to emphasise your point 4: you MUST change the "ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow" to False in the "Properties" window, NOT by double-clicking the connection manager and going into the Editor.  If you do the latter, SSIS "helpfully" decides that all your columns are going to be called Column1, Column2 etc and trashes all your mappings

Comment: Thanks so much.  This was very helpful since I had SPACE() columns defined.

Answer (score 4):

#### Avoiding column names in the flat file output:

Double-click the *Flat File Connection Manager* to open the *`Flat File Connection Manager Editor`*

On the *Flat File Connection Manager Editor*, uncheck the box **`Column names in the first data row`**.

This will prevent flat file connection manager from writing the column names to the flat file output.

[image: Flat File Connection Manager Editor]

Comment: BUt If I uncheck it the Header column part displayed in the data portion...its there in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have header in the file - you can simply skip the first row. See screenshot from @user756519 answer.
Set `Header rows to skip` to **1**