# How do I select a SQL dataset where values in the first row are the column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, dynamic-sql

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID RowType Col_1       Col_2     Col_3       ... Col_n
1  HDR     FirstName   LastName  Birthdate
2  DTL     Steve       Bramblet  1989-01-01
3  DTL     Bob         Marley    1967-03-12
4  DTL     Mickey      Mouse     1921-04-25
```

And I want to return a table or dataset that looks like this:

```
ID    FirstName    LastName    Birthdate
2     Steve        Bramblet    1989-01-01
3     Bob          Marley      1967-03-12
4     Mickey       Mouse       1921-04-25
```

where n = 255 (so there's a limit of 255 Col_ fields)

***EDIT: The data in the HDR row is arbitrary so I'm just using FirstName, LastName, Birthdate as examples. This is why I thought it will need to be dynamic SQL since the column names I want to end up with will change based on the values in the HDR row. THX! ***

If there's a purely SQL solution that is what I'm after. It's going into an ETL process (SSIS) so I could use a Script task if all else fails.

Even if I could return a single row that would be a solution. I was thinking there might be a dynamic sql solution for something like this:

```
select Col_1 as FirstName, Col_2 as LastName, Col_3 as Birthdate
```

Comment: An SSIS data flow needs to have a constant column set at design time. In other words, you can't define a single data flow where the column names/types/count can change. Were you trying to get a single data flow that could work with a dynamic set of inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, posted an answer but I completely misread that you had your desired column headers as *data* in the source table.

One trivial solution (though it requires more IO) would be to dump the table data to a flat file without headers, then read it back in, but this time tell SSIS that the first row has headers, and ignore the `RowType` column. Make sure you sort the data correctly before writing it out to the intermediate file!

To dump to a file without headers, you have to set `ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow` to `false`. Set this in the properties window, not by editing the connection. More info in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098443/how-to-prevent-ssis-from-writing-column-names-to-the-flat-file-output)

If you have a lot of data, this is obviously very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your first data snippet is already in a oracle table or not but it is in a CSV file then you have option during loading to skip headers.

If data is already in table then you can use `UNION` to get desired result

```
Select * from table name where rowtype=‘HRD’
union
select * from table name where rowtype=‘DTL’
```

If you need First Name etc as Column header then you need not to do anything. Design destination table columns as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using `row_number`. Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3ce35048a6e0873c40be4b2bcc485f1c).

```
with cte as
(
  select
    *,
    row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from myTable
)

select
    ID,
    Col_1 as FirstName,
    Col_2 as LastName,
    Col_3 as Birthdate
from cte
where rn > 1
```

output:

```
| id  | firstname | lastname | birthdate  |
| --- | --------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 2   | Steve     | Bramblet | 1989-01-01 |
| 3   | Bob       | Marley   | 1967-03-12 |
| 4   | Mickey    | Mouse    | 1921-04-25 |
```

Comment: thanks @zealous but did you see my edit? The data are just examples, I need columns with names that are the values in the HDR row, not specifically firstname, lastname, and birthdate. I hope I'm explaining it correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, well. There is a pure SSIS approach, assumed the source is a SQL table. Here it is, rather sketchy.

1. Create a Variable *oColSet* with type `Object`, and 255 variables of type `String` and names sColName_1, sColName_2 ... sColName_255.
2. Create a SQL Task with query like `select top(1) Col_1, Col_2, ... Col_255 from Src where RowType = 'HDR'`, set task properties *ResultSet = Full Result Set*, on result set tab - set *Result Name* to 0 and *Variable Name* to `oColSet`.
3. Add ForEach Loop enumerator, set it as `ForEach ADO Enumerator`, *ADO object source variable* - set to `oColSet`, *Enumeration mode = Rows in the first table*. Then, on the *Variable Mappings* tab - define as such example (`Variable - Index`) - sColName_1 - 0, sColName_2 - 1, ... sColName_255 - 254.
4. Create a variable sSQLQuery with type `String` and *Variable Expression* like

   ```
   "SELECT Col_1 AS ["+@[User::sColName_1]+"], 
       Col_2 AS ["+@[User::sColName_2]+"], 
       ...
       Col_255 AS ["+@[User::sColName_255]+"]
    FROM Src WHERE RowType='DTL'"
   ```
5. In the ForEach Loop - add your dataflow, in the OLEDB Source - set *Data access mode* to *SQL command from variable* and provide variable name `User::sSQLQuery`. On the Data Flow itself - set *DelayValidation=true*.

The main idea of this design - retrieve all column names and store it in temp variable (step 2). Then step 3 does parsing and places all results into corresponding variables, 1 column (0th) - into sColName_1 etc. Step 4 defines a SQL command as an expression, which is evaluated every time when the variable is read. Finally, in the ForEach Loop (where parsing is done) - you perform your dataflow.

Limitations of SSIS - data types and column names should be the same at runtime as at design time. If you need to further store your dataset into SQL - let me know, so I could adjust the proposed solution.